# Domain, Nginx and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker

I try to install WordPress on an nginx docker container.
my domain

```
blog.example.com
```

points to the ip

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/wordpress/
```

the backend is working like a charm with a domain like this:

```
blog.example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
```

In the Frontend when i want to visit my page it automatically switches

```
blog.example.com
```

to

```
blog.example.com/wordpress
```

my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name blog.example.com;
   root /var/www/;
   index index.php;

   location /wordpress/{
      try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;

   }
   location ~\.php${
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ⁽.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $args;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

WP seems to be installed to `/var/www`, not `/var/www/wordpress`.

Your `location` block needs to be.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

In addition, there is a lot more to running a WordPress site via nginx. [WPORG has a guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).